# Finding operator norm of functional

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I am given a functional $F:C([0,1],\|x\|_\infty) \to \mathbb C $ by formula

$$F(f)=2\int_0^{1/2}f(t)dt \text{ - } \int_{1/2}^1f(t)dt$$

I should find its operator norm. I've found that $\|F\| \le 3/2$ using some basic inequalities, but am unable to prove the equality here, not to mention that I could be wrong and $3/2$ is not the optimal bound.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Approximate the function
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}1,&x\leq 1/2\\
-1,&x>1/2 \end{cases}
$$
with continuous functions.

For this, we take 
the sequence of norm $1$ continuous functions:
$$
f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
1,&x\leq 1/2-1/n\\
-n(x-1/2),&1/2-1/n<x\leq 1/2+1/n\\
-1,&1/2+1/n<x\leq 1
\end{cases}
$$
I leave to you to verify $F(f_n)\uparrow 3/2$

Comment: Brilliant, the idea is pretty clear and applicable in other examples. Thanks.